# Conda SSL Error while trying to py_install

Tags: python, r, ssl-certificate, miniconda, reticulate

I try the following codes in R (Windows):

```
reticulate::py_install("capiq-excel", repos = "https://pypi.org/simple/",
                       extra_args = c("--trusted-host", "pypi.org",
                                      "--trusted-host", "pypi.python.org",
                                      "--trusted-host", "files.pythonhosted.org"))
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed
>
> CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.
>
> Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

I've tried the following command in Miniconda prompt, but it did not solve the issue:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

How can I resolve this issue?